# ASP.NET MVC How to link 2 Models - need some explanation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have read some here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-4 and set some stuck

```
namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public class Artist
    {
        public int ArtistId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public class Album
    {
        public int      AlbumId     { get; set; }
        public int      GenreId     { get; set; }
        public int      ArtistId    { get; set; }
        public string   Title       { get; set; }
        public decimal  Price       { get; set; }
        public string   AlbumArtUrl { get; set; }
        public Genre    Genre       { get; set; }
        public Artist   Artist      { get; set; }
    }
}
namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public partial class Genre
    {
        public int      GenreId     { get; set; }
        public string   Name        { get; set; }
        public string   Description { get; set; }
        public List<Album> Albums   { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In the Album Class, why they have:

```
public Genre    Genre       { get; set; }
public Artist   Artist      { get; set; }
```

And in the Genre class, why they have:

```
        public List<Album> Albums   { get; set; }
```

Can you explan for me why we should have these fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properties provide access to the linked objects on each object, they allow us to do things in code like -

```
var GenreName = album.Genre.Name
var ArtistName = album.Artist.Name
```

Similarly you could iterate through the Albums linked to a Genre using the `public List<Album> Albums` property. The Entity framework will populate the necessary linked properties on objects with the relevant data from the database. The linked property data can be loaded immediately or lazily depending on how the entity framework code is called.

As an example here's some code that pulls out albums that are linked to a particular genre, notice how the `Include` function is called, the function ensures that `Album` data is pulled from the database at the same time the `Genre` information is pulled -

```
public ActionResult Browse(string genre)
 {
    // Retrieve Genre and its Associated Albums from database
    var genreModel = storeDB.Genres.Include("Albums")
        .Single(g => g.Name == genre);

    return View(genreModel);
 }
```

Comment: Can you tell me how about "public List<Album> Albums", I see that one Genre may have many Album, so maybe that is the Idea of the code, but I'm new to C#...

Comment: That's it - one Genre may have many albums and `List<Album>` will hold all the albums for that Genre. Album only has a single `genre` property and a single `Artist` property as each album only has one artist and on genre.

Answer (score 1):

Totally logical.
each album has an you listen to has a genre and an artist. so he created a custom object of both genre and artist 
 example this:

```
    public class Artist
{
    public int ArtistId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

}

this is done to map it to a table in a database most probably that has an ID and a name of the artist.
similarly to genre.

as for the List
each genre like Rock has multiple albums inside it thats why he decared a list of the object of album inside the object genre that he is using..
he will add list of objects albums to genre and then maybe save them in the database as a one to many relationship.
well he could have saved a list of ID of the AlbumID that would be better, but im not sure of the full logic maybe is is using the full object elsewhere