# Displaying a model list item variable from a view that uses a different model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a setup similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849681/asp-net-mvc-how-to-link-2-models-need-some-explanation) and am trying to use a html helper to display a specific item from the list of items in a separate model based on a lambda expression.

I'll use Album and Genre in my example.

```
namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public class Album
    {
        public int      AlbumId     { get; set; }
        public int      GenreId     { get; set; }
        public int      ArtistId    { get; set; }
        public string   Title       { get; set; }
        public decimal  Price       { get; set; }
        public string   AlbumArtUrl { get; set; }
        public Genre    Genre       { get; set; }
    }
}
namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public partial class Genre
    {
        public int      GenreId     { get; set; }
        public string   Name        { get; set; }
        public string   Description { get; set; }
        public string   ThisAlbumId     { get; set; }
        public List<Album> Albums   { get; set; }
    }
}
```

There is a view that uses the Genre model and I'm attempting to display an Album.Title where Album.AlbumId == Genre.AlbumId

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Albums.Where(x=>x.AlbumId == Model.ThisAlbumId))
{
     <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</td>
}
```

It should only return one AlbumId.  Currently I'm getting a "Value cannot be null" error.  I've also tried

```
  <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Album.Where(x => x.Id == model.ThisAlbumId).FirstOrDefault())</td>
```

but I get error:

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your lambda expression modelItem => item doesn't make sense, use item => item instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **first** attempt looks fine. It would have been nice to see the stack trace of the error. But if you're getting a **value cannot be null**, then it's most probably because `Model` is null; i.e. the view's model is not being instantiated and passed on. From your code, I can infer that the view's model is `Genre` class, you should check in the action method whether you're passing the model to the view. If you did it correctly, the relevant part in the action method should look somewhat like this:

```
    var model = new Genre
    {
        //set relevant properties
    };
    //set other relevant 'model' properties, if any
    return View("YourViewName", model);
```

Concerning the **second** error:

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions

This piece of code:

```
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Album.Where(x => x.Id == model.ThisAlbumId).FirstOrDefault())</td>
```

should be changed to

```
<td>@Model.Album.Where(x => x.Id == Model.ThisAlbumId).FirstOrDefault()</td>
```

What I've done is eliminate the `.DisplayFor`. As the error shows, template methods like `.DisPlayFor` cannot be used with methods or other lambda-type expressions.

However, another issue is that since you're calling `.FirstOrDefault` which will return an `Album` instance or `null`. Since what you want is the `.AlbumId` property, then I suggest the following edit:

```
<td>
 @{
     var oneItem = Model.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == Model.ThisAlbumId);
     //Notice that I used "Model" and not "model". The difference is huge!
     if (oneItem != null)
     {
        Html.Raw(oneItem.AlbumId);
     }
  }
</td>
```

Comment: That helps me get further down the debug chain.  It appears that Model.Albums is returning null.  I replaced Model.ThisAlbumId with something I knew is in the database just to be sure.  My real project is different.  New_Monitoring_Data refers to the Genre and New_Contact refers to Album.

Strack trace: http://pastebin.com/8nL0apzW

Comment: I can see. `parameter name: source` refers to the enumerable, ie, the list. However my answer assumes that wasn't the case, so I will expect you still had the problem even after you made sure it wasn't null. You should probably be getting the second error message you talked about in the question, so you should make the modification I proposed.

Comment: Your comments were most helpful.  I ended up using a Tuple instead of this route but still used your advice in the new approach.  Thank you